# Replace if uppercase letter is followed by lowercase letter in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script that is extracting data from a few Excel spreadsheets into a text file. It then looks for an uppercase 'D' and precedes it with a line break, then deletes any empty lines. What I'm running into is that there are some fields containing names starting with D and it is adding a new line when I don't need it to. IE, Field1 format is'H1234DavidLastname' and Field2 format is 'DCODE'. I need to add a new line in Field2 but skip over Field1.

Here is what I have now:

```
$PRN = ("file_path")

$con = Get-Content $PRN

$con | % { $_.Replace("D", "`r`nD") } | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | Set-Content $PRN | Out-Null
```

I tried using an if statement to only look for fields with uppercase letters but the results are the same as the original script.

```
if ($con -cmatch "[A-Z]"){

$con | % { $_.Replace("D", "`r`nD") } | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | Set-Content $PRN | Out-Null

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share more of the example text file data?

Comment: Sure. Each line of text would be similar to this format:


H12345DavidLastname  3  123ABC  DCODE  123456


All codes begin with the letter D and need a line break added before them. The only other place a D would show up would be in someone's name. Names are the only field that would have lowercase letters. I need to be able to remove all empty lines while preserving the original spacing.

Comment: ```'H12345DavidLastname 3 123ABC DCODE 123456' -creplace "D(?![a-z])", "`r`n$&"``` (see [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)).

Comment: @JosefZ

Thanks! It worked by modifying my original Replace with the creplace and negative lookahead you provided.